Is it a condition to redo shahadah when one commits major shirk?
I'm assuming, Repentance is the condition for "redoing" shahadah. Another assumption made by me is the foundations of religion (Asl ad deen) is same from first jinn to last human.
In the incident of calf and bani israil . Allah set execution as condition for acceptance of repentance for those muslims who worshipped the calf.

However, Allah did not accept the repentance of those who worshipped the calf except by death. Those who were willing to be executed would receive Allah’s pardon and enter jannah. Those who did not surrender themselves for execution would never be forgiven by Allah. This was a gruelling trial of sincerity the whole of Bani Israel, because Allah had commanded that the wrongdoers were to be executed by the hands of the believers.

Source: https://hadithoftheday.com/prophet-musa-as-part-v/
Since repentance wasn't accepted by Allah until execution, how did muslims of bani israil redo shahadah after committing major shirk?
So ultimately the question, where is it mentioned in Quran and sunnah that a muslim who commits major shirk needs to redo shahadah?
Islamweb doesn't say to repeat shahadah to a person who commited shirk.
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.islamweb.net/amp/en/fatwa/89591/
